# Flask SQLAlchemy Set expire_on_commit=False

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In Flask-SQLAlchemy, at:

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/queries.html

you access to your session via `db.session`.

How do you make the session accessed via `db.session` have

`expire_on_commit=False`

I tried `db.session.expire_on_commit = False` but this does not appera to take affect.

Comment: You need to add it to the app settings with `SQLALCHEMY_EXPIRE_ON_COMMIT`, but I've got to ask, why do you want to do this and what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `session_options` dictionary when making the database object.

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={"expire_on_commit": False})
```